# subsheaf isomorphic to sheaf of compatible germs?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I was wondering if the following elementary statement about sheaves is true: If $\mathcal{F}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$ (both are sheaves on $X$, a topological space) with stalks we denote by $\mathcal{F}_P$ for each $P \in X$. Then is $F$ isomorphic to the sheaf $\mathcal{F}^{\dagger}$ whose sections $\mathcal{F}^{\dagger}(U)$ are defined to be the group of functions $f: U \rightarrow \amalg \mathcal{F}_P$ such that for all $P \in X$, $f(P) \in \mathcal{F}_P$ and moreover, there is some open neighborhood of $P$, call it $V \subset U$ and section $s \in \mathcal{G}(V)$ such that $f(Q) = s|{Q}$  for all $Q \in V$.

So informally, given a subsheaf $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{G}$, is $\mathcal{F}$ isomorphic to the sheaf formed by taking collections of germs of $\mathcal{F}$ that are compatible with respect to $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: $X$ is a topological space, I have added this into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In particular, if we set $Q := P$, then for each $P \in U$ we get an open neighborhood of $P$, $V \subseteq U$, and section $s \in \mathcal{G}(V)$ such that $f(P) = s|P$.  By definition of stalks, this implies that for some other open neighborhood of $P$, $V' \subseteq V$, we have $s|_{V'} = t|_{V'}$ where $t$ is a representative of $f(P) \in \mathcal{F}_P$.  Thus, we see that $f$ satisfies the compatibility condition required for $f$ to induce an element of $\mathcal{F}(U)$.

A closely related fact is: for any $g \in \mathcal{G}(U)$, we have that $g \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ if and only if $g_x \in \mathcal{F}_x$ for each $x \in U$.  (And in general, $\{ x \in U \mid g_x \in \mathcal{F}_x \}$ is an open subset of $U$.  This relates to the notion of the *subobject classifier* $\Omega$, which is a sheaf of sets such that $\Omega(U) = \{ V \subseteq U \mid V \mathrm{~open} \}$, and the relation between subsheaves of $\mathcal{G}$ and morphisms of sheaves $\mathcal{G} \to \Omega$.)

Comment: Thanks! I am having some trouble figuring out what is wrong in Roland's counterexample in the comment above, do you have any insight on this?

EDIT: It seems they deleted it, so I will restate it: Take $\mathcal{F}$ to be any sheaf and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the sheaf with $\mathcal{G}(U)$ consisting of all functions $f: U \rightarrow \amalg_{P \in U} \mathcal{F}_P$ with $f(P) \in \mathcal{F}_P$ for all $P \in U$. Is $\mathcal{F}^{\dagger} \neq \mathcal{G}$?

Comment: Well, in Roland's counterexample (from what I remember seeing, I don't see the comment any more): suppose $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathcal{F}_x \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ for each $x$.  Then the counterexample constructed $\mathcal{G}$ with $\mathcal{G}(U) = \prod_{x\in U} \mathbb{Z}$.  Then, if you have for example a section of $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{R})$ where $g = (g_x)_{x\in \mathbb{R}}, g_x = \delta_{x,0}$, then there is no $V, s$ at $P = 0$.  We have $\mathcal{G}_0 \simeq \underset{\rightarrow}\lim \prod_{x\in (-1/n, 1/n)} \mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: but for any element of $\mathcal{G}_0$ which agrees with $g$ on some open neighborhood $(-1/n, 1/n)$, its stalk at 0 is still not in $\mathcal{F}_0$ so it cannot satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: Ah, I see so I guess the mistake was to believe that $\mathcal{G}_P \cong \mathcal{F}_P$!

Comment: Yes I removed my comment because I misread something in your post. Anyway, the stalks of $U\mapsto\prod_{P\in U}\mathcal{F}_P$ is not $\mathcal{F}_P$ as Daniel Schepler explained.